# NestJS can't resolve dependencies of the JWT_MODULE_OPTIONS

Tags: typescript, module, nestjs

I'm failed to compile with this error:

*Nest can't resolve dependencies of the JWT_MODULE_OPTIONS (?). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the JwtModule context. +52ms*

I saw similar dependencies problems with modules & services, but they didn't work for me. Using JwtModule in my **auth.module.ts**:

```
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User, Role]),
        ConfigModule,
        PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
        JwtModule.registerAsync({
            inject: [ConfigService],
            useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
                secretOrPrivateKey: config.jwtSecret,
                type: configService.dbType as any,
                host: configService.dbHost,
                port: configService.dbPort,
                username: configService.dbUsername,
                password: configService.dbPassword,
                database: configService.dbName,
                entities: ['./src/data/entities/*.ts'],
                signOptions: {
                    expiresIn: config.expiresIn,
                },
            }),
        }),

    ],
    providers: [AuthService, JwtStrategy],
    controllers: [AuthController],
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

I have no idea how to fix this bug... Using **jwt 6.1.1**

**Edit:** In my previous project use jwt 6.0.0, so I downgrade it, but problem not fix.

Comment: Really quick question: why are you passing database options to your JWT module?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you are mixing the TypeORMModule configuration with the JWTModule configuration.

According to `@nestjs/jwt` [source code](https://github.com/nestjs/jwt/blob/master/lib/interfaces/jwt-module-options.interface.ts#L9) (and [docs](https://github.com/nestjs/jwt#async-options)), `secretOrPrivateKey` and `signOptions`. All the other parameters seem to be part of the TypeORMModule configuration.

Second, the ConfigService (which is dependency [0] of the JWT module) does not seem to exist anywhere in your code. So you are missing an import to a module where the ConfigService exists inside.

This is why the dependency load is failing (and that is what the error is throwing means)

Note that in your code you are missing an import of a module (`ConfigModule` in the following sample), which is the module that holds the ConfigService. Otherwise there is no way to inject this ConfigService from nowhere!

```
JwtModule.registerAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule], // Missing this
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    signOptions: {
       expiresIn: config.expiresIn,
    },
    secretOrPrivateKey: config.jwtSecret,
  }),
  inject: [ConfigService], 
}),
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed help (bow). But work in my appModule is global wrong. I receive compile errors for every controllers and providers.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57473726/nestjs-cant-resolve-dependencies-of-the-authservices

Answer (score 2):

I somehow got it to work by adding

```
JwtModule.registerAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule], // Missing this
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    signOptions: {
       expiresIn: config.expiresIn,
    },
    secretOrPrivateKey: config.jwtSecret,
  }),
  inject: [ConfigService], 
}),
```

in the **app.module.ts** and **auth.module.ts**

Answer (score 1):

You can make a separate module for it (SharedModule)

make sure you have the following packages installed

```
npm i --save @nestjs/jwt
npm i --save @nestjs/passport
```

*(optional, if you go with MongoDB/Mongoose)*

```
  npm i --save @nestjs/mongoose
```

> **shared.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [
      PassportModule.register({
          defaultStrategy: 'jwt',
        }),
        JwtModule.register({
          secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
          signOptions: {
            expiresIn: '2 days',
          },
        }),
    
   ],
   providers: [JwtStrategy],
   exports: [JwtStrategy, PassportModule]
})
```

> **jwt.strategy.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(@InjectModel('User') private collection: Model<User>) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: JwtPayload): Promise<User> {
    const { username } = payload;
    const user = await this.collection.findOne({ username });

    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('JwtStrategy unauthorized');
    }

    return user;
  }
}
```

Now where you want to use it, just import in your module SharedModule.
In your controllers use the following decorator

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard())
```