# NestJS can't resolve dependencies of the AuthServices

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

After [first problem with JWT_MODULE_OPTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57463523/nestjs-cant-resolve-dependencies-of-the-jwt-module-options), back to old problem who I thought I was fixed. It turned out that when I "fix" old problem create the new with JWT.

**So again can't compile:**

*Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService (?, RoleRepository, JwtService). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the AppModule context. +25ms*

It's really strange, because this way work on another my project and can't understand where I'm wrong. Here is the **auth.service.ts**:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(User) private readonly userRepo: Repository<User>,
        @InjectRepository(Role) private readonly rolesRepo: Repository<Role>,
        private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
    ) { }
```

It get role and `jwtService` but the problem is with `User`, the path is correct. Here is **app.module.ts**:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule, AuthModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: configService.dbType as any,
        host: configService.dbHost,
        port: configService.dbPort,
        username: configService.dbUsername,
        password: configService.dbPassword,
        database: configService.dbName,
        entities: ['./src/data/entities/*.ts'],
      }),
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController, AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Have the same compile error for controllers & providers & can't understand what is wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be missing the `TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])` import. Typically, all entities are imported in dedicated feature modules. If you only have one module (i.e. `AppModule`) you need to put the `forFeature` import there in addition to the `forRoot` import.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({...}),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User, Role]),
  ],
```

Comment: You are right, thanks. I have all entities in forFeature in CoreModule on my previous project. But when add User & Role in forFeature receive another compile error with AuthService:

Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService (UserRepository, RoleRepository, ?). Please make sure that the argument at index [2] is available in the AppModule context. +21ms 

I tried to add jwtService in forFeature but doesn't work...

Comment: I added - inject: [ConfigService, JwtService], and think it's ok for now, but get new error...

Comment: The `jwtService` has nothing to do with the `TypeormModule`.  When you import the `JwtModule` it exposes the `JwtService`; but only in the module with the import. Have a look at this thread to learn how you can export a service to use it in other modules: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51819504/inject-nestjs-service-from-another-module/51821523#51821523

Comment: Yes, when inject JwtService a receive this error ---  Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TypeOrmModuleOptions (ConfigService, ?). Please make sure that the argument at index [1] is available in the TypeOrmCoreModule context. +25ms --- if I'll fix this, back to AuthService error...

Answer (score 0):

The global problem was that I try to add AuthService & AuthController twice. So I remove them from **app.module.ts** and just export  AuthService from **auth.module.ts**: