# NestJS can't resolve dependencies of the JWT_MODULE_OPTIONS (Same problem, different solution)

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, nestjs, nestjs-config

**This is not duplicate! I saw same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57463523/nestjs-cant-resolve-dependencies-of-the-jwt-module-options), but solution not helped.**

My NestJS instance is not starting because of this problem:

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the JWT_MODULE_OPTIONS (?). Please make sure that the argument ConfigService at index [0] is available in the JwtModule context.
```

My auth.module.ts:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User, Token]),
    DatabaseModule,
    UserModule,
    ConfigModule,
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule], // Missing this
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        signOptions: {
          expiresIn: configService.get<string>('JWT_EXPIRATION'),
        },
        secretOrPrivateKey: configService.get<string>('JWT_SECRET'),
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

and this is my app.module.ts (Entry Module):

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: '.development.env',
    }),
    AuthModule,
    UserModule,
    DatabaseModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I am importing module correctly by `imports: [ConfigModule]`, but still I am getting error, that injection failed, because module is not imported.

My ConfigModule is 100% imported into app as my log say: `ConfigModule dependencies initialized`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using barrel index.ts files?

Comment: @raychz I am not

Answer (score 1):

The issue, assuming you are using the `@nestjs/config` module, was a bug in the module's code for version < 0.2.3. [In the latest version](https://github.com/nestjs/config/issues/82) there was a fix to the issue. If you upgrade to 0.2.3 with `npm i @nestjs/config@latest` it should run fine.