# nestjs jwt implementation is stuck - Nest can't resolve dependencies of the JWT_MODULE_OPTIONS (?)

Tags: node.js, typescript, jwt, nestjs

I'm trying to implement JWT with NestJs. In my `user.module.ts`, I have added following configuration:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { UserResolver } from './user.resolver';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AuthHelper } from './auth/auth.helper';
import { JwtStrategy } from './auth/auth.strategy';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';

@Module({
  imports: [
    // PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt', property: 'user' }),
    // JwtModule.registerAsync({
    //   inject: [ConfigService],
    //   useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => ({
    //     secret: 'secret',
    //     signOptions: { expiresIn: 36000000 },
    //   }),
    // }),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]),
  ],
  providers: [UserResolver, UserService], // AuthHelper, JwtStrategy],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

Whenever I uncomment these lines, I get some issues.

Here are some relevant files:

**auth.strategy.ts**

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { User } from '../entities/user.entity';
import { AuthHelper } from './auth.helper';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  @Inject(AuthHelper)
  private readonly helper: AuthHelper;

  constructor(@Inject(ConfigService) config: ConfigService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      secretOrKey: 'KhubSecret',
      ignoreExpiration: true,
    });
  }

  private validate(payload: string): Promise<User | never> {
    return this.helper.validateUser(payload);
  }
}
```

**auth.guard.ts**

```
import { Injectable, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard, IAuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { User } from '../entities/user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') implements IAuthGuard {
  public handleRequest(err: unknown, user: User): any {
    return user;
  }

  public async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    await super.canActivate(context);

    const { user } = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

    return user ? true : false;
  }
}
```

**auth.helper.ts**:

```
import {
  Injectable,
  HttpException,
  HttpStatus,
  UnauthorizedException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import { User } from '../entities/user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class AuthHelper {
  @InjectRepository(User)
  private readonly repository: Repository<User>;

  private readonly jwt: JwtService;

  constructor(jwt: JwtService) {
    this.jwt = jwt;
  }

  public async decode(token: string): Promise<unknown> {
    return this.jwt.decode(token, null);
  }

  public async validateUser(decoded: any): Promise<User> {
    return this.repository.findOne(decoded.id);
  }

  public generateToken(user: User): string {
    return this.jwt.sign({
      id: user.userId,
      username: user.username,
    });
  }

  public isPasswordValid(password: string, userPassword: string): boolean {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, userPassword);
  }

  public encodePassword(password: string): string {
    const salt: string = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);

    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);
  }
  private async validate(token: string): Promise<boolean | never> {
    const decoded: unknown = this.jwt.verify(token);

    if (!decoded) {
      throw new HttpException('Forbidden', HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }

    const user: User = await this.validateUser(decoded);

    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

I get some error like this:

```
[Nest] 18360  - 05/10/2022, 18:14:42   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the JWT_MODULE_OPTIONS (?). Please make sure that the argument ConfigService at index [0] is available in the JwtModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If ConfigService is a provider, is it part of the current JwtModule?
- If ConfigService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within JwtModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing ConfigService */ ]
  })

Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the JWT_MODULE_OPTIONS (?). Please make sure that the argument ConfigService at index [0] is available in the JwtModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If ConfigService is a provider, is it part of the current JwtModule?
- If ConfigService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within JwtModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing ConfigService */ ]
  })
```

I have already tested and implemented these solutions:

- [NestJS can't resolve dependencies of the JWT_MODULE_OPTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57463523/10305444)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution. I hope it would help.

In your auth strategy add this:

```
  constructor() {
    super({
     jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
     secretOrKey: 'KhubSecret',
     ignoreExpiration: true,
   });
  }
```

instead of:

```
  constructor(@Inject(ConfigService) config: ConfigService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      secretOrKey: 'KhubSecret',
      ignoreExpiration: true,
     });
    }
```

**In Short, Remove**

```
@Inject(ConfigService) config: ConfigService
```

**from your constructor**

Answer (score 0):

From the immediate error you've provided, I'll assume that your `ConfigModule` is not global. This means that you'll need to import the `ConfigModule` in the `JwtModule.registerAsync()` call (in the `imports` array). Another option would be to make your `ConfigModule` global (`@nestjs/config` has an option for this) so that you already have access to `ConfigService`.

Comment: Hey, a little more push would have been helpful...

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad what do you mean? I responded to the best of my ability with the error and code you've provided. Is there more you think I could have done?